# SQL Server 2008 R2: Concatenate alias name with column value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have `Product` table with columns `QtyID`, `Qty` and `Year_ID`. I also have a table `tbl_Years` with `ID` and `Year`.

I have a simple `SELECT` statement with `SUM` calculation of `Qty`:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Qty) AS /*Sum_of_year_2016*/
FROM 
    Product p
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Years ty ON p.Year_ID = ty.Year_ID
WHERE
    ty.Year_ID = 6;
```

I want to define an alias name of `Sum_of_year_2016` for the `SUM(Qty)` value.

Note: the year should be fetched from the `tbl_Years` table.

My attempt:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Qty) AS 'Sum_of_year_' + ty.Year
FROM 
    Product p
INNER JOIN  
    tbl_Years ty ON p.Year_ID = ty.Year_ID
WHERE 
    ty.Year_ID = 6;
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Syntax error; incorrect syntax near '+'.

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1613968-392-1.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL to get custom alias:

```
DECLARE @year NVARCHAR(4) = (SELECT TOP 1 Year FROM  tbl_Years WHERE Year_id=6);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'SELECT 
    SUM(Qty) AS ' + QUOTENAME('Sum_of_year_' + @year) +
' FROM Product p
INNER JOIN tbl_Years ty 
ON p.Year_ID = ty.Year_ID
Where ty.Year_ID = 6;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```