# Can I concat text and Getdate() as column header?

Tags: sql, sql-server

is it possible to get something like `concat('TMVDAY',DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())-1)` as column header?
so the column header (assuming today is Friday (starting from Monday)) will be  "**TMVDAY5**"

best I can think is some thing like this: `SELECT GETDATE() as concat('TMVDAY',DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())-1);`

I'm using ms sql server.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes - using dynamic sql. But usually "column header" implies a resultset which you do not discuss and your query generates a scalar value. It might be more effective to discuss your goal.

Comment: Yes stuff like that is usually handled by the application displaying the data and formatting/etc  (UI, webiste, other)

Comment: You should fix your data model.  You are storing data in different columns that should be in separate rows.

Comment: You might check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706630/sql-server-2008-r2-concatenate-alias-name-with-column-value

Comment: @SMor: The idea is that, I need to select from correct column with out writing too many if  (or when) statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be achieved through dynamic SQL:

```
declare @header varchar(20)
declare @dsql varchar(200)

set @header=concat('TMVDAY',DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())-1)
set @dsql = 'select getdate() ' + @header 

EXEC sp_sqlexec  @dsql
```

But it would be better if you express your actual situation if it's not just a simple scaler value.

Comment: You are welcome. If you feel that this answer solved your problem you might accept my answer by clicking green check. This way focuses would be more on unsolved problems.